# Amazon Product Advertising API AWS.InvalidAssociate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I have a problem with the access key. I'm registered with the same account (same main email) to the affiliate program of Amazon in Italy, UK, Spain, France, Deutschland.

I'm testing API calls via Scratchpad.

The call works correctly with:

`Marketplace = webservices.amazon.it/`

`Marketplace = webservices.amazon.es/`

`Marketplace = webservices.amazon.fr/`

For the .de and .co.uk regions I get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ItemSearchErrorResponse
    xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
    <Error>
        <Code>AWS.InvalidAssociate</Code>
        <Message>Your AKIAJXVQWNYTVRITZESA is not registered as an Amazon Associate. Please register as an associate at https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/gp/associates/join/landing/main.html.</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestID>305dcc04-7f45-4141-bcd1-6e49f36b1568</RequestID>
</ItemSearchErrorResponse>
```

I can not understand the reason for this error.

Can someone help me?

Thanks